# Wrong usage of Classtag in Scala?

Tags: scala, class

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag


class IntStorage {
  var variable: Int = 5
}


class testing[T : ClassTag] {
  var example = Array.ofDim[T](10, 10)
  def testFunc(): Int = example(0)(0).variable
}
```

Error: value variable is not a member of T

I do not understand why I get this error, even though I use a Classtag.

Comment: Why do you even have a generic? Why not just using `IntStorage` directly? Also, why using an `Array` instead of a real collection?

Comment: This was just a fictional example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Well, you may show more code to see the real problem. Anyways, it seems Silvio answer is what you were looking for. - PS: The advice of not using `Arrays` still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassTag` is fine. But you declared `testing` to work for *any* class, not just `IntStorage`. What if I call `new testing[String]()`? `String` is a perfectly valid class with a class tag, but it doesn't have a `variable` field. I could call it with any class.

Is it possible you meant

```
class testing[T <: IntStorage : ClassTag] { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that too, but I got the error: "] expected but <: found
"

Comment: Try the other permutation. `T <: IntStorage : ClassTag`. Scala is fickle about the order on those, and I always get it backwards. My mistake!

Comment: I know that this is a totally different question, but what if IntStorage is an abstract class and some subclasses of it have functions that are not defined in IntStorage? If I try to call these functions from Testing, I get an error as expected. Is there a way to fix that or is it impossible?

Comment: Do those subclass functions come from a common parent interface? If so, you can use that interface as your upper bound to call those functions. If not, then as far as the JVM (and Scala, for that matter) is concerned, they're completely unrelated functions which happen to have the same name. Scala will let you play around with that a bit with structural types and intersections, but that dips into Java reflection and just gets weird, so it's best to avoid it if possible.

Comment: I'm new to Scala and I don't quite understand what you mean by common parent Interface? They are all subclasses of the abstract class intStorage, so they all extend intStorage. But there are also subclasses of IntStorage that do not have those functions (so I can't declare those functions in intStorage since that would mean that every subclass must have those functions, which is not true in my case).

Comment: @HeloKitay then you can't call those functions, because doing so would break Liskov. You either need to declare a new interface, or use a typeclass or maybe make it an ADT and use pattern matching. Without more context it os hard to provide the best alternative.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I get it, thank you!

Comment: @HeloKitay I recommend you formulate your problem in words carefully and then ask another SO question about it. It sounds like an interesting problem to tackle, once fully formulated, but the comment section of an answer may not be the best place to address that.